# Navagraha & incense

Tags: worship, astrology, navagraha

Which incense should be offered to the navagraha individually for graha shanti?
I think Surya likes the smell of lotus flowers, but I have no idea what smells the other grahas like.
Does someone know?

Comment: Do you want only the fragrances or flowers they like? I have given them in the answer. Do you need anything more?

Answer (score 4):

The procedure of worship of Navagrahas is mentioned in the Padma Purana Srishti Khanda Chapter 61, 82. It was said by Vyasa to Vaishampayana and other disciples. The incense and the colours they like are also mentioned along with the procedure of worship to individual planets.

- Surya -  Hibiscus (Japa flower), Indian Oleander (Karavira), red saffron flowers of spring. Arka leaves (Calotropis gigantea).
- Chandra - White fragrant flowers and garlands.
- Kuja - As, Kuja or Mangala is Lohitanga, red flowers and anointments are offered to please him.
- Budha - Sandal, incense of fragrant flowers.
- Guru - Yellow coloured fragrant flowers.
- Shukra - With white sandal, white flowers.
- Shanaishchara - with black sandal, black flowers, pieces of cloth of that
  kind (i.e. of black colour), oil and sesamum.
- Rahu - Flowers and objects same as Shanaishchara.
- Ketu - The objects that are same as Shanaishchara.

Answer (score 0):

Each graha has its own incense as same as the Flowers mentioned in the above answer.

Planet   - Incense(Dhoopam)

Sun      - Sandal

Moon     - Benzoin

Mars     - Goggul

Mercury  - Pure Camphor

Jupiter  - Lotus/Lily petals

Venus    - Clove

Saturn   - Black wood

Rahu     - Mustard

Ketu     - Red wood

Using the above dhoopams on corresponding days or offering in homam brings a good result to physical and mental health.